# 'Aufgabe' Object has no attribute 'beantworten' (Python 3.6)

Tags: python-3.x

I am learning python, and I am at the OOP chapter now. So this is a program I made with a Math game but it doesn't work.

Source Code:
https://paste bin.com/VsTEnK9s

It gives me this error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> AttributeError: 'Aufgabe' object has no attribute 'beantworten'

Please help me, I would appreciate it.

Comment: please embed the code directly in the question. You can *also* link to pastebin, but fix the url.  Questions/Answers that rely on outside links may be deleted, as the post would become useless if the link were to become unavailable.

Comment: Also, you need to be more specific on *exactly* what tour specific issue is. "It doesn't work" is not useful information. Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, then `edit` your question, so that others may help.